# How to loop through each row in a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, web-scraping

I have an excel file like below with a set of names and their google scholar links.

```
ID   Name   Link
1    A      www.abc.com
2    B      www.def.com
3    C      www.ghi.com
```

I have written a code to read the excel file, browse each link using a for loop, within each loop -scrape information from each link and write it in a new file. The code is as follows.

```
File=[]
for i in arr:
   driver.get(i)
   columns={}
   columns['Name'] = driver.find_element_by_id()
   columns['Citations'] = driver.find_element_by_id()
   File.append(columns)
```

My question is I want to include a column 'ID' in my new file which is the same as the column 'ID' as my excel file. Essentially, I want the first row of the column'ID' in the first iteration of the for loop, the second row of the column'ID' in the second iteration of the loop and so on. Can someone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving them as a dictionary, save them as a DataFrame and assign a new column, called source with the id:

```
File=[]
for i in arr:
   driver.get(i)
   columns={}
   columns['Name'] = driver.find_element_by_id()
   columns['Citations'] = driver.find_element_by_id()
   File.append(pd.DataFrame(columns).assign(source=i))
```

to get only a single dataframe out of it u then can use:

```
pd.concat(File)
```

Comment: In my code, i is each element of the column 'Link'. So, the above code gives me a column called source in which the link column appears. But, I need the ID column. My original dataframe is named df. So, instead of i, I use  source=df.ID?? But, that doesnt work too